# How can I run (recenter) after (call-interactive ...) that jumps to a buffer?

Tags: buffers, motion, navigation

I would like to jump to a buffer using `rtags` for eg.

Example snippet:

```
(defun generic-lookup () "Follow link/goto line."
  (interactive)
  (cond
    ((string= major-mode "c-mode")
      (progn
        (call-interactively 'rtags-find-symbol-at-point)
        (call-interactively 'recenter)))))
```

However this gives the error:

```
progn: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.
```

How to recenter after calling a function that opens a new buffer?

Comment: In general, I resolve problems of this nature by identifying the window to be recentered and wrapping the recenter command in `(with-selected-window WINDOW (recenter))`.  You'll probably need to `M-x find-function RET rtags-find-symbol-at-point RET` and modify it accordingly (e.g., by creating a new function) or use an advice-thing-a-majig.  As you know, we obtain the WINDOW by using things like `get-buffer-window` if we know the buffer (by name or by its lisp object), but not the window ...  I don't know if there is any benefit to *interactively* calling the `recenter` command, but ...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried using `(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window) (recenter))` - but this didn't work (interactively or not). Putting both functions inside a lambda which is called interactively also failed.

Comment: `get-buffer-window` requires the correct argument as to the BUFFER ... either a valid buffer-name, or a valid buffer lisp object.  In fact, you can even evaluate that command in the minibuffer and it will work without generating an error assuming the buffer exists:  `(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window BUFFER) (recenter))`  If it works in the minibuffer with `M-x eval-expression`, then you are almost home free.  There is also a second optional argument dealing with potentially ALL-FRAMES -- if that is applicable, you may wish to read the doc-string and see the available customizations.

Comment: I don't use rtags, but I like to recenter things.  The first thing to try is usually `(setq next-error-recenter '(4))`, which makes anything calling `next-error` do a recenter.  Maybe `rtags` uses `next-error`, maybe not.  Glancing at the source, it looks like `rtags-buffer-name` might be the buffer name you're after.  Also, there's an `rtags-switch-to-buffer-hook`.

Comment: @jpkotta, I got `rtags-switch-to-buffer-hook` working, even so. This seems like the kind of think that could be done in a generic way.